# Mongoose: How to convert all my existing documents to new schema

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a `Product` schema, with `categories:[string]`. I want to change my `Product` schema, as the `categories` should be a SubDocument, with the objectId of a category and the name of the category. I use Mongoose, so I changed the ProductSchema to this:

```
const ProductSchema = new Schema<IProduct>({
    categories: [CategorySchema],
});
```

How can I update now all my existing Products to the new schema?
I started to write an endpoint in my Express backend like that, but name is a function in the end of this:

```
router.get('/convertCategories', async function (req, res) {
  const products = await Product.find({ 'name.en': '280 big csavar' });
  products.forEach((product) => {
    // @ts-ignore
    product.categories = product.categories.map((category) => {
      return {
        name: Category,
        _id: Category.findOne({ name: category }),
      };
    });
    console.log(product.categories);
  });
  res.send('Finished');
});
```

What should I change?

Answer (score 0):

I think we need to delete the old `product` schema and create a new `product` schema with categories as a subdocument:

```
// Create a new Mongoose model for the new schema.
const NewProductUpdatedSchema = new Schema({
  categories: [CategorySchema],
});

// Create a new Mongoose instance for the new model.
const NewProductUpdatedModel = mongoose.model("NewProduct", NewProductUpdatedSchema);

// Use the `findOneAndUpdate()` method to update each existing Product document with the new schema.
const products = await Product.find();

products.forEach((product) => {
  await NewProductUpdatedModel.findOneAndUpdate({ _id: product._id }, product, { upsert: true });
});

// Delete the old schema.
// **cautious**: make sure you don't need old schema anymore
mongoose.model("Product").remove();
```

Comment: @Koli did it solved your issue , if yes please accept it as answer